# Substituir imagem (logo no canto superior esquerdo da página) por uma segunda logo (editada) Rolar a página (Scroll)

Tags: jquery, css, bootstrap, rolamento

Boa tarde!
Estou precisando que, ao rolar a página do meu site pela barra de rolagem ou scroll do mouse, a logotipo seja substituida.

Minha logo está inserida na página por meio de uma classe no bootstrap.css
Segue:

```
.logo1{
    background: url(../img/logoo.png) no-repeat;
    height: 164px;
    width: 172px;
    padding: 15px 15px;
    font-size: 18px;
    line-height: 20px;
    float: left;
    position: absolute;

}

.logo2{
    background: url(../img/logoclube.png) no-repeat;
    height: 78px;
    width: 61px;
    padding: 15px 15px;
    font-size: 18px;
    line-height: 20px;
    float: left;
    position: absolute;

}
```

O que eu preciso é que, ao rolar a página, a classe chamada .logo1 seja substituída pela classe .logo2 e consequentemente a imagem original da página inicial seja substituida.

Answer (score 0):

Poderá explorar outras formas, mas utilizando as funções jQuery `.scroll()`, `.removeClass()` e `.addClass()`, poderá solucionar o problema:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(window).scroll(function() {
       $('.logo1').removeClass('logo1').addClass('logo2');  
    });
});
</script>
```

No seu html adicione o script jQuery antes de qualquer código javascript:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score -1):

Para realizar a troca da classe `.logo1` pela classe `.logo2` ao rolar a página, você precisará usar JavaScript para detectar quando a rolagem ocorre e, em seguida, modificar a classe do elemento que contém a logo. Aqui está um exemplo de como você pode fazer isso:

1. Primeiro, você precisará adicionar um ID ao elemento que contém a logo para que seja mais fácil de selecioná-lo com JavaScript. Vou assumir que esse elemento tem a tag `<div>` com o ID "logo-container":

```html
<div id="logo-container" class="logo1"></div>
```

2. Em seguida, você pode usar JavaScript para ouvir o evento de rolagem e fazer a troca das classes quando a página for rolada. Aqui está um exemplo de como você pode fazer isso:

```html
<script>
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
    const logoContainer = document.getElementById("logo-container");
    const logo1Class = "logo1";
    const logo2Class = "logo2";
    const scrollThreshold = 100; // Define a quantidade de rolagem em pixels para a troca de classes

    // Função para trocar as classes de logo ao rolar a página
    function handleScroll() {
        if (window.scrollY >= scrollThreshold) {
            logoContainer.classList.remove(logo1Class);
            logoContainer.classList.add(logo2Class);
        } else {
            logoContainer.classList.remove(logo2Class);
            logoContainer.classList.add(logo1Class);
        }
    }

    // Adicionar ouvinte de evento de rolagem
    window.addEventListener("scroll", handleScroll);
});
</script>
```

Neste exemplo, a função `handleScroll()` é chamada sempre que ocorre uma rolagem na página. Ela verifica a posição vertical de rolagem (`window.scrollY`) e, se essa posição for maior ou igual ao valor definido em `scrollThreshold`, ela substitui a classe `.logo1` pela classe `.logo2`. Caso contrário, ela faz a substituição inversa.

Certifique-se de incluir esse código JavaScript após o elemento `<div>` que contém a logo e a tag `<script>` que carrega o Bootstrap CSS no seu arquivo HTML.

Lembre-se de ajustar o valor de `scrollThreshold` de acordo com a quantidade de rolagem em pixels que você deseja que ocorra antes da troca das classes. Experimente diferentes valores para encontrar o que melhor se adapta ao seu layout.